# Proving a function is integrable if it is bounded and, for every $\epsilon >0$, there is a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U_P-L_P < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

The following has to be proven in one of my problem sets but I'm having trouble going about it. If I could have some help on where to start it would be very appreciated. Notationally, $U_P$ denotes the upper sum over some partition $P$, and $L_P$ denotes the lower sum over some partition $P$.

Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[a,b]$. If $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists$ a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U_P-L_P<\epsilon$, then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. Note that the definition of integrability being used (all we have learned so far) is "$f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ iff $\inf_{P}(U_p)=\sup_P(L_P)$."

Comment: Haven't you confused the two? It should be that $\sup_{P}(L_P)=\inf_{P}(U_P)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks.

Comment: Look at any intro to analysis textbook ...

Comment: This is an easy consequence of definitions of upper and lower sums and sup/inf.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:***

If integrable, find a partition $P_0$ such that $\inf_{P}(U_p)>U_{P_0}-\epsilon$ and $L_{P_0}+\epsilon>\sup_{P}(L_p)$.

In the other direction, assume that it is not integrable, and show that there must be a partition not satisfying the inequality.

Given two partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$, use refinements to obtain one partition to work with.